# How do I measure how long the program is executed

Tags: java, clock

I am creating a **Java Application** where the OS's System Clock is adjusted from time to time. (so it's like a peer-to-peer NTP experiment)

I am looking for a Java construct that is something like a virtual clock where in I can still get the age of the application in milliseconds from the time it was executed. Because if I will always just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, it might give me false age of the application.

Is there something like that? without actually creating another thread solely for it?

Comment: How about [`java.lang.System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())?

Comment: May I ask you why you think you get the false age with `currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: @Gerret the OP says that system time way be slewed during the running of the application, this means that the application age would be incorrect.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` still wont work. They are almost the same with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
I am looking for a way to monitor the age of the application while other applications can remotely modify my System clock. That's why if I'll still use `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` it might return a false outcome.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ahh ok but why is that so? I mean if I get the currentMillis, save it (at starting) and after I subtract the currentMillis (after running), I think that should be a right number or not??

Comment: If you had read the documentation I provided then you might have come across this sentence _This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time_ and further _The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine_. Changes to the system clock do not affect `nanoTime`.

Comment: @Gerret If I take the current time then move the system clock back one minute and take the current time again then the second time will reflect the change. The difference between the two times will be out by one minute...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Well but that is normaly not happening, if you do it that way it actully should return the right age of the application I think.

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo May you could post how you calculate the age of your program?

Comment: that's a good one you have there @BoristheSpider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculte the elapsed time of your program you have multiple possibilities. Not all will fit your program because your system time could be change while your program is running.

### currentTimeMillis()

With that method you get the current time of your system in millisecounds. If you want to calculate the runnning time of your program you could save the currentTime in a long variable. When you want the time the program is needed, you just simply subtract the currentTime now with your saved one.

*Save the time when your program starts!*

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

*Subtract the end time and the start time!*

```
long need = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

Keep in mind that if you **change** the **system time** you get a **wrong time**!

### nanoTime()

With nanoTime you get the elapsed time of your Virtual Java Machine in nanosecounds. If you want to calculate the elapsed time, you have to do the same like with currentTimeMillis(). At the beginning you save the time and at the end you substract it.

*Save the time when your program starts!*

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
```

*Subtract the end time and the start time!*

```
long need = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000; // divide to get millisecounds
```

Keep in mind that you get the **right time**, even if you **change** the **system time**, because you use the time of the Virtual Java Machine!

### Difference

You only get the right elapsed time with `System.nanoTime()`. You should not use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, unless you do not mind that your result is wrong. `currentTimeMillis()` is to measure *"wall-clock"* time. When your system time is updateing, you simply get a wrong time. `nanoTime()` is actully mad for that, that you calculate the elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this directly in Java, the only solution to this is to record the time differences applied to the system clock and takes this into account in your application.

Of course this depends greatly on the underlying operating system and the tools used to adjust the system clock.

Comment: That is actully complete wrong... Sure you are able to calculate the elapsed time! And you are able to use nanoTime wich is not affacted by the system clock

Comment: I've experienced what GerritCap said. It really depends on the tools and the OS. However, I also would like to implement @BoristheSpider arithmetic procedure. But I think it can compromise some floating points. What do you think?